# How to change llama2 hyperparameters (temperature, max_tokens) for a prompt through vertex AI endpoint?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, large-language-model, llama

I deployed Llama213b to a vertex AI endpoint through their GUI. It was fairly straightforwards.

Following the example [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/samples/snippets/prediction_service/predict_custom_trained_model_sample.py) I can prompt an endpoint with the llama2 model pretty easily with something like: `instances = [{"prompt": prompt} for prompt in prompt_list]`. However, it seems as though I cannot change the hyperparameters for the model like `temperature` and `max_new_tokens`.

Adding temperature to [this](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/samples/snippets/prediction_service/predict_custom_trained_model_sample.py#L44) dictionary didn't seem to work. I also tried something like `instances = [{"prompt": prompt,"temperature":0} for prompt in prompt_list]` which did not make the outputs deterministic.

Is there a way to output what possible parameters there are for the model? And how do I interface with them?